# Problems with calling function inside function using `this`

Tags: javascript, this, self

```
window.onerror = function(e){alert(e)};
function main(){
    this.work = [];
    this.start_working = function() {
        try{
            if(this.work.length > 0){
                var y = this.work.shift();
                y.func(y.args);
            }
        }
        catch(e){alert(e)};
    };
    this.add_work = function(f, a){
        this.work.push({func:f, args:a});
    };
    this.foo = function(){
        function footoo(){alert("bar");}
        this.add_work(footoo);
    };
    this.foothree = function(){
        this.add_work(this.foo);
    };
    this.start = function(){
        setInterval(function(){this.start_working();}.bind(this), 1);
    };
};
x = new main();
x.start();
x.foothree();
```

This is the watered down version of a function I am using elsewhere to run animations sequentially.

Expected behavior:

`this.foothree` is processed by the interval adding foo to the interval. `this.foo` is then processed adding `footoo` to the interval which is finally processed alerting "bar".

Problem:

when `this.foothree` is processed, an error is thrown:

> TypeError: this.add_work is not a function.

---

Why don't I use something simpler:

Basically I need a function which allows me to compose a more complex animation made of simpler animations to the queue to be processed so I can reuse that animation. `Foothree` in this instance is just simulating a call which would add the real animation, `footoo`, to the queue to be processed. `Footoo` would be composed of simpler animations, `foo`, which would be executed sequentially.

Comment: Why don't you just use `setInterval(function(){this.start_working();}.bind(this), 1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` returns the `[[ThisValue]]` property of the `EnvironmentRecord` of the `LexicalEnvironment` of the `ExecutionContext` of the running function (see [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-environment-records)).

Its value depends on [how the function is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context). If you call

```
this.foo = function(){
    function footoo(){alert("bar");}
    this.add_work(footoo);
};
```

in the function being declared there is no `add_work` method.

You should adopt var `_self = this;` pattern in order to point the correct calling context.

Basically the code should be rewritten as follows:

```
function main(){
    var _self = this;

    this.work = [];
    this.start_working = function() {
        try{
            if(_self.work.length > 0){
                var y = _self.work.shift();
                y.func(y.args);
            }
        }
        catch(e){alert(e)};
    };
    this.add_work = function(f, a){
        _self.work.push({func:f, args:a});
    };
    this.foo = function(){
        function footoo(){alert("bar");}
        _self.add_work(footoo);
    };
    this.foothree = function(){
        _self.add_work(_self.foo);
    };
    this.start = function(){
        setInterval(function(){_self.start_working();}, 1);
    };
};
```

**Edit:**

removed `.bind(this)` from original code.

Comment: Working perfectly now! Thanks!

Comment: You probably should use either `_self` or `bind`. `setInterval(function(){_self.start_working();}.bind(_self), 1);` this doesn't make sense to do to me

Comment: using `var _self = this;` is bad practice IMO. Should pass in this reference explicitly using bind or call or apply.

Comment: -1 "`this` is related to the context in which it is called" is not correct. `this` depends on how the function is called and whether the target has been bound with `bind`.

Comment: Ben and Rikin, please post examples that are superior to this answer.  The more knowledge the better.

Comment: ...by way of explanation: the execution context is distinct from `this`.

Comment: @BenAston Do you mean that it does not point the execution context itself but points at the object inside that context (i.e. points at the `this` of the enclosing execution context)?

Comment: @BenAston Edited again, hope my english is good enough to adapt correctly what said in the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

This question has two components.

First it is a question about `this` in JavaScript aka the "target" or "receiver" of a function.

The target of a function in JavaScript depends on whether you are in strict mode, how the function was called and whether it was bound using `bind`.

Assuming strict mode (you should always put `'use strict';` at the top of your JavaScript):

```
foo(); // this inside foo will be undefined

a.foo(); // this inside foo will be a

a.foo.call(o); // this inside foo will be o

a.foo.apply(o); // this inside foo will be o

a.foo.bind(o)(); // this inside foo will be o
```

The second aspect to this question is what the author is attempting to do. I am pretty sure the complexity he is introducing to chain animations is unnecessary, and that he should be using `requestAnimationFrame`, but discussion of this would require another question.

Example:

```js
function foo() {
    document.write('foo', this, '<br/>');
    bar();
}


function bar() {
    document.write('bar', this, '<br/>');
}

foo();
document.write('------<br/>');
foo.call({});
```